# Render different plots based on if/else on existence of reactive variable

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create an app that allows 1) a user to hover over scatter plot points, which displays a label associated with the point, and 2) search for a specific point by label.

Currently, to highlight a point, I re-plot the graph each time the user submits a search term, adding that single point on top of rest of the points that have been plotted.

In order to avoid the server re-plotting before the user finishes typing the label, I require that the "search" button be pressed. However, I'm struggling to get the plot to display BEFORE the user has searched for any labels.

Here's what I have so far:

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggiraph)

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), label = paste("gene", seq(100)))
head(df)
           x           y  label
1 -0.3383215  0.91212341 gene 1
2 -0.5318215 -0.63273778 gene 2
3  1.1281345 -0.01296204 gene 3
4 -1.2964345 -2.21689946 gene 4
5  1.5877938 -0.24993362 gene 5
6  0.6385419  0.07849135 gene 6

gg_scatter <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point_interactive(aes(tooltip = label, data_id = label))


ui <- fluidPage(

  textInput(inputId = "gene_symbol",
            label = "Search for a gene",
            placeholder = "gene 1"),
  actionButton(inputId = "go",
               label = "Search"),
  girafeOutput("scatterplot"),
  textOutput("message")

)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  gene_search <- eventReactive(input$go, {
    input$gene_symbol
  })

  output$scatterplot <-
      renderGirafe({
        gg_scatter_highlight <- gg_scatter +
          geom_point_interactive(data = subset(df, label == gene_search()),
                                 tooltip = gene_search(),
                                 size = 3,
                                 color = "red")
        girafe(code = print(gg_scatter_highlight),
               options = list(opts_selection(type = "single")))
      })

  output$message <- renderText({
    if(sum(is.element(df$label, req(gene_search()))) == 0) {
      paste("Gene not found")
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I'm trying to add something like this to `output$scatterplot`:

```r
 output$scatterplot <-
      renderGirafe({
        ## If the user has not searched for anything, plot without any points highlighted
        if(!isTruthy(gene_search)) {
          girafe(code = print(gg_scatter),
                 options = list(opts_selection(type = "single")))
        }
        ## Highlight the point that the user searched for
        else {
          gg_scatter_highlight <- gg_scatter +
            geom_point_interactive(data = subset(df, label == gene_search()),
                                   tooltip = gene_search(),
                                   size = 3,
                                   color = "red")
          girafe(code = print(gg_scatter_highlight),
                 options = list(opts_selection(type = "single")))
        }
      })
```

... Unfortunately this still results in no plot being displayed until a label is searched.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `ignoreNULL = FALSE` in `eventReactive` to have a default value at the beginning.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggiraph)

gg_scatter <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point_interactive(aes(tooltip = label, data_id = label))


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  textInput(inputId = "gene_symbol",
            label = "Search for a gene",
            placeholder = "gene 1"),
  actionButton(inputId = "go",
               label = "Search"),
  girafeOutput("scatterplot"),
  textOutput("message")
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  gene_search <- eventReactive(input$go, {
    input$gene_symbol
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  output$scatterplot <-
    renderGirafe({
        gg_scatter_highlight <- gg_scatter +
          geom_point_interactive(data = subset(df, label == gene_search()),
                                 tooltip = gene_search(),
                                 size = 3,
                                 color = "red")
  
      girafe(code = print(gg_scatter_highlight),
             options = list(opts_selection(type = "single")))
    })
  
  output$message <- renderText({
    if(sum(is.element(df$label, req(gene_search()))) == 0) {
      paste("Gene not found")
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```